# jQuery notification plug-in

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, notifications

I'm new to JS and am writing a notification plug-in. Currently I'm calling this plug-in like so:

```
$.notifyBar({
    cls: "error",
    html: "message"
});
```

By default it stays for 2 seconds and disappears. What I want to do is, if delay set to 0, then notifybar will not disappear automatically. I want it to disappear it programmatically, in ajax success function. How can I modify this plug-in to realize my idea?

http://jsfiddle.net/YQaS4/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just set the `delay` very high:

```
$.notifyBar({
  cls: "error",
  html: "message"
});
```

And then close the bar with:

```
$(".jquery-notify-bar").slideUp();
```